# Book set in Norman Ireland with Celtic mythology

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a book I read, within the last 10 years, and I don't think it was published too long before I read it.

Here's what I remember.

It follows a Norman knight sometime after the invasion of Ireland. He has been sent their either because he inherited some land there or as a form of punishment.

There is a very strong Celtic mythology presence, Redcaps play a very prominent role as antagonists, killing quite a lot of people.

The Morrigan is also in it she is very manipulative and trying to start a war. She can turn into a crow as per her mythology.

There are various other celtic gods/spirits etc at work throughout the book, both trying to help and hinder the knight.

It may be part of a series though I've only read the first one if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description put me in mind of The Wanders and The Watchers series by [Caiseal Mór](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caiseal_M%C3%B3r), ,which are set in pre-Christian Ireland. Redcaps and the Morrigan feature in these as well.

Looking at his bibliography, he has also written another trilogy set in Norman Ireland, the first of which [The Well of Yearning](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/768068.The_Well_of_Yearning), features a Knight exiled to Ireland.

Note: I haven't read these, only the first trilogy, and the first book of the Watchers

Comment: It’s the well of yearning! I thought there was a well involved somewhere. Thanks!